# Publish messages to Oracle Cloud stream service

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, publish, producer-consumer

I am working on OCI Streaming Service and looking for a way where I can directly publish message to stream without using any code. I created an application in Spring boot using which I am able to push and consume messages from OCI stream. But due to some tech restrictions I am looking for an approach where I don't need to use any type of code to publish data.

Can anyone please give some suggestions on this ?

My findings so far, got this [article](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/streaming/20180418/Message/PutMessages) which tells about PutMessage API.

I tried using the same and as per doc and formed a URL `https://<host-name>:9092/20180418/streams/{streamId}/messages` with BASIC AUTH.

When hitting this URL from postman i am getting a **Could not get any response msg.**

Comment: 9092 is a Kafka port, have you tried 9000 or 443?

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a bug in the example, it should be an array of messages:

```js
{
  "messages":
  [
    {
      "key": null,
      "value": "VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2cu"
    },
    {
      "key": null,
      "value": "UGFjayBteSBib3ggd2l0aCBmaXZlIGRvemVuIGxpcXVvciBqdWdzLg=="
    }
  ]
}
```